# How can I display data sent through ajax in django？

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views

I have the following setup but I can't seem to display content in ajax although it works if I go directly to the url.

```
<div class="test" style="width:200px; height:200px; border-style:solid;">
<button class="testb">click here</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".testb").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../profile_page_tags_get/' + 'primary',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $(".test").html( "<div>" + data + "</div>")
      }
    })
});
```

View function:

```
def profile_page_tags_get(request, edit_type):
    data = {}
    if edit_type == 'primary':
        p_options = Primary.objects.all()
        data['p_options'] =  list(p_options.values_list())
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")
```

Url:

```
 url(r'^profile_page_tags_get/(?P<edit_type>.*)/$', views.profile_page_tags_get, name='profile_page_tags_get'),
```

Comment: So what actually happens?

Comment: Open browsers console and inspect the result of request

Comment: @DanielRoseman nothing gets displayed. blank. but when I visit the url directly the data does get returned.

Comment: Can you put some debug info in `success` block and see if the block got executed? Can you `alert` the data your ajax returned correctly? Also, don't hard code your url in ajax, use django url template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url.

Comment: But what happens? Is the request being sent? Do you see it on your Django console? What do you see in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: it turns out the url was wrong. I used django url template tag and it worked.